# Proving a lower bound on a recurrence by converting log base

Tags: algorithm

There's a problem in "Introduction to Algorithms" that says: (4.4-6)

> Argue that the solution to the recurrence `T(n) = T(n/3) + T(2*n/3) + cn`
>   where `c` is a constant is  Ω(n log<sub>2</sub>n) by appealing to a recursion tree.

I use a recursion tree and at last I get `T(N) >= n log3n`.
I don't know the next step to show that `T(N) >= n log2n`,
I also Googled it and somehow I feel something is wrong with the answers, because they say when `T(N) >= n log3n` then `T(N) >= n log2n` (but `log3n` is not greater than `log2n`).

Comment: how did you deduce that log_3(n) > log_2(n)? plot these two functions and you'll see that log_3(n) is always less than log_2(n) that's obvious.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it's the other way round. You're right. `log_3(n) < log_2(n)`. That's what you get for typing stuff before writing it on paper...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In asymptotic bounds, the base of the logarithm doesn't matter since it's only a constant variation.This is due to the change of base in logarithm.

log<sub>a</sub> x= log<sub>b</sub> x/log<sub>b</sub> a

This is why people don't write base in asymptotic bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Recall [the definition of big omega](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations): `f(n)` is in `Omega(g(n))`, if `f` is bounded below by `g` asymptotically. Or, if you like it more mathy:

[image: definition of Big Omega]

Let's define `f(n) = n * log_3(n)` and `g(n) = n * log_2(n)`.

Now, if we can find a constant `c` so that `f(n) > c * g(n)`, then we have shown that `f(n)` is in `Omega(g(n))`.

```
    log_3(n) = log_2(n) / log_2(3)
    log_2(3) ~= 1.585 < 2
=>  log_3(n) > 2 * log_2(n)
=>  n * log_3(n) > 2 * n * log_2(n)
=>  f(n) > c * g(n)
```

for our chosen value of `c = 2` (you can, of course, choose any other value, as long as `c > log_2(3)`.